# Disks showing up under Disk Management but not under Get-PhysicalDisk

Tags: windows-server-2019, windows-cluster

I have a 2 node Windows server 2019 Cluster running on Vmware ESXi 6.5

I added 3 25GB disks to the server after it had been created.

I can see the 3 disks in the disk management tool

[image]

If I run Get-PhysicalDisk it will only list one disk

If I run wmic diskdrive list brief it will list all for.

Why are these disks not showing up under Get-PhysicalDisk

[image]

I have tried many ways to get the disks, initialize disk, reset disk, make MBR make GPT, convert to dynamic, create and mount to dive letter. Nothing seems to work.

Any more info I can provide please let me know

Comment: have you solved this problem?