# Windows 10 Pro, disk is visible in get-disk but not get-physicaldisk

Tags: windows-10, storage-spaces

I have a Win 10 pro machine with one storage spaces pool.
There are 6 disks: one with host OS, 4 disks are part of storage pool, last one is problematic.

### Problem

I can not add the last disk to a storage pool.
The disk also demonstrate strange behavior: it is visible by `get-disk` command and not visible by `get-physicaldisk`

### Disk drivers are ok:

I can initialize disk, assign drive letter and write data on it.

[image]

### `get-disk` and `get-physicaldisk` output

[image]

### Add to storage pool

If I try to add disk to storage pool I get this error
Can't prepare drives, Close all applications that are accessing the drive
[image]

### What I have tried

- there is a similar unsolved problem on SF and not much info on google: [Disks showing up under Disk Management but not under Get-PhysicalDisk](https://serverfault.com/questions/1015843/disks-showing-up-under-disk-management-but-not-under-get-physicaldisk)
- I tried to initialize disk, format and clean it with `diskpart`

Answer (score 0):

did you find a solution to your problem?
I have basically the same problem.

Which Windows version are you using?
I am on 20H2.
I found a similar issue regarding storage spaces on 2004/20H1

For me it looks like this:
[get-disk vs get-physicaldisk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYF9T.png)

Comment: Nothing. I use Windows Pro N 10 1909

Comment: So, for myself I solved this by doing a backup, deleting the old storage pool and creating a new one.
(I also noted that Windows 10 ENT can use ReFS on Storage Spaces)